# python-docx getting docx information

Tags: python-docx

I was trying to copy the whole text from a docx file with all the styles, font information, images and table data. I get the text from the docx file but when I try to get the font information with `doc.paragraphs[0].runs[0].style.font.name` it shows `None`. Can anyone help me?